# condição para mostrar dados na combobox

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

Galera é o seguinte tenho dois formulários, um de cadastro de empreendimento e outro de cadastro de processo, sendo que no de processo tem uma `ComboBox` onde é puxado todos os empreendimentos que foram cadastrados, lembrando que o formulário de processo é chamado assim que for finalizado o cadastro de empreendimento.

O usuário do sistema pode abrir os dois formulários dependendo da sua necessidade, no entanto,caso o usuário abrisse o formulário de empreendimento e realizasse um cadastro assim que fosse chamado o formulário de processo gostaria que a `ComboBox` mostrasse apenas o ultimo empreendimentos cadastrado, senão se o usuário quiser apenas ver os empreendimentos cadastrado no forme de processo fosse exibido todos os empreendimentos na `ComboBox`.

Fala Pessoal segue trecho apenas das partes mais importantes do código:

**Formulário de cadastro de empreendimento**

```
<?php
session_start();
require './config/conexao.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && empty($_SESSION['email']) == FALSE) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['senha']) && empty($_SESSION['senha']) == FALSE) {        
    }
} else {
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit();
}
?>

<form  action="recebe_cad_empreendimento.php"  method="POST" name="frmempreendimento" id="frmempreendimento">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading"> 
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><strong>DADOS DO EMPREENDIMENTO / ATIVIDADE</strong></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="empreendimento"><strong>NOME DO EMPREENDIMENTO*</strong></label>                                  
                            <input type="text" name="empreendimento" id="empreendimento" class="form-control">   
                        </div>                                  
                    </div>
                </div>                           
            </div>
        </div>                                             
    </div>                                                          
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="REALIZAR CADASTRO" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;"/>
            <button  class="btn btn-danger"><a href="home.php"  style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;text-decoration: none;">CANCELAR CADASTRO</a></button><br/><br/>
        </div>   
    </div> 
</form>
```

**Pagina que recebe os dados do formulario de empreendimento (`Recebe_cad_empreendiemeto.php`)**

```
<?php
session_start();
require './config/conexao.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && empty($_SESSION['email']) == FALSE) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['senha']) && empty($_SESSION['senha']) == FALSE) {

    }
} else {
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit();
}
if (isset($_POST['nome_empreendimento']) && empty($_POST['nome_empreendimento']) == FALSE) {

    $nome_empreendimento = strtoupper(addslashes($_POST['nome_empreendimento']));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_empreendimento(nome_empreendimento)"
            . "VALUES(UPPER('$nome_empreendimento')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    ?>               
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EMPREENDIMENTO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="cad_licenca.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CONTINUAR CADASTRO</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**Formulário de cadastro de processo**

```
<?php
session_start();
require './config/conexao.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && empty($_SESSION['email']) == FALSE) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['senha']) && empty($_SESSION['senha']) == FALSE) {

    }
} else {
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<form  action="recebe_cad_processo.php"  method="POST" name="frmprocesso" id="frmprocesso">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading"> 
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><strong>DADOS DO PROCESSO</strong></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">                                                
                            <label for="empreendimento"><strong>SELECIONE O EMPREENDIMENTO*</strong></label><a href="cad_empreendimento.php" style="float: right;font-size: 16px"><strong>caso não encontre,faça o cadastro - aqui</strong></a><br/>
                            <select name="empreendimento" id="empreendimento" class="form-control" autofocus="">
                                <option value="">--- SELECIONE ---</option>
                                <?php
                                $parametro_empreendimento = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_empreendimento");
                                $empreendimento = "SELECT *FROM tb_empreendimento WHERE nome_empreendimento LIKE '%$parametro_empreendimento' ORDER BY nome_empreendimento";
                                $recebe_empreendimento = mysqli_query($con, $empreendimento);
                                while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($recebe_empreendimento)) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $linha['codigo_empreendimento'] . '">' . $linha['nome_empreendimento'] . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>                                                                       
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="numero_processo"><strong>NÚMERO DO PROCESSO *</strong></label><br/>
                                <input type="number" name="numero_processo" id="numero_processo" class="form-control" autofocus=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="REALIZAR CADASTRO" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;"/>
            <button  class="btn btn-danger"><a href="home.php"  style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;text-decoration: none;">CANCELAR CADASTRO</a></button><br/><br/>
        </div>   
    </div>
</form>
```

**Pagina que recebe os dados do formulario de processo (`Recebe_cad_processo.php`)**

```
<?php
session_start();
require './config/conexao.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && empty($_SESSION['email']) == FALSE) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['senha']) && empty($_SESSION['senha']) == FALSE) {

    }
} else {
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['empreendimento']) && empty($_POST['empreendimento']) == FALSE) {
    if (isset($_POST['numero_processo']) && empty($_POST['numero_processo']) == FALSE) {

        $empreendimento = strtoupper(addslashes($_POST['empreendimento']));
        $numero_processo = strtoupper(addslashes($_POST['numero_processo']));

        if ($numero_processo < 0) {
            ?>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ERRO! O NÚMERO DO PROCESSO INFORMADO É INVÁLIDO</h4>                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="cad_licenca.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">POR FAVOR! INFORME OUTRO NÚMERO</button></a>
                            <a href="home.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CANCELAR</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }

//verrificando se ja existe no banco de dados o numero do processo informado
        $consulta_processo = "SELECT *FROM tb_processo WHERE numero_processo ='" . $_POST['numero_processo'] . "' ";
        $recebe_consulta = mysqli_query($con, $consulta_processo);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($recebe_consulta) > 0) {
            ?>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ERRO! JÁ EXISTE UM PROCESSO COM O NÚMERO INFORMADO</h4>                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="cad_licenca.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">POR FAVOR! INFORME OUTRO NÚMERO</button></a>
                            <a href="home.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CANCELAR</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            </script>

            <?php
        } else {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_processo(fk4_codigo_empreendimento,numero_processo)"
                    . "VALUES('$empreendimento','$numero_processo')";
            mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            ?>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">PROCESSO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO!</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="cad_licenca.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CONTINUAR CADASTRO</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ERRO! POR FAVOR PREENCHA O FORMULÁRIO</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="cad_processo.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><strong>VOLTAR PARA O FORMULÁRIO DE CADASTRO</strong></button></a>
                <a href="home.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><strong>CANCELAR</strong></button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: e cadê o seu código para que possamos ajudar? xD

Comment: Antes de fazer uma pergunta de uma olhada nisso aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Mostre o código da aplicação.